# Combine Multiple Rows Into A Single Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a stored procedure for reporting purposes and I need to combine rows in a single column but I can't find a way to do this.  I have four tables, Case, Debtor, DebtorAddress and CaseNote.  Rather than try to do this in a single statement I decided to create a temp table with the columns needed, populate the ones that occupy a single row, then use an update statement to combine the multiple rows of the last column needed into a single row.  My temp table has rows for CApKey (the ID of the Case table), OwnerName (from Debtor), Address (from DebtorAddress, and Note.  For each Case there may be multiple Notes (stored in the CaseNote table).  So I may have Case #1, with a CApKey value of 1, OwerName of John Jones, Address of 1234 Main St.  There may be one Note the says 'Called and left message', another that says 'Sent letter', and another that says 'Left a second voicemail', etc.  I'd like to combine the three notes into a single row with Note values of Called and left a message, Sent Letter, and Left a second voicemail.  I can use space, period, or comma as a delimiter.  I found a way to do the update in theory but I'm getting an error that the sub-query returned more than 1 value.  Below is the "heart" of the procedure.  I've been wracking my brain on this for two days now. Any assistance is greatly appreciated in advance.  Here is the statement I'm trying:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
CaseKey                 int,
OwnerName               varchar(500),
Address                 varchar(500),
Note                    varchar(MAX)
)

DECLARE @val Varchar(MAX);

INSERT INTO #temp 
    (CaseKey, OwnerName, Address)
    SELECT ca.CApKey, DEFirstName + ' ' + DELastName, da.DAAddress1
    FROM [Case] ca INNER JOIN Debtor de ON ca.CApKey = de.CApKey INNER JOIN DebtorAddress da ON ca.CApKey = da.CApKey
    WHERE ca.LFpKey = @LFpKey AND de.DEIsPrimary = 1

UPDATE #temp SET Note = 
    (SELECT COALESCE(@val + ', ' + CANNote, CANNote) 
    FROM CaseNote WHERE CApKey = 51) 
    --SELECT @val;)
SELECT * FROM #temp
```

Thanks!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a big help.  The run-on paragraph is rather hard to decipher.

Comment: Good luck with having anyone read through all that and make sense of it. Instead why not add some sample data and expected results - much clearer.

Comment: SQL server 2016 or newer (I think) has string_agg().  I think you might want that.

Comment: As other's said, this is unreadable. Post sample data and desired results, not a description and a query that may not be relevant. If you want to aggregate multiple values into one you can use `STRING_AGG` in SQL Server 2017 and later. In previous versions, the best option uses SQLCLR and the second best uses XML and STUFF. It looks like you tried to use the quirky UPDATE technique, which takes [twice the time of the XML technique and 3.5 as long as SQLCLR](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation)

Comment: Depending on your use for the collected `Note` strings, you might want to consider storing them in a single [`xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/xml-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) column. That ensures that you can recognize where each note starts and ends, but the encoding of some characters may raise other issues. You ought to be able to produce the result without needing the temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly, you need to combine all the notes.

Get your data, queried from the 4 tables into a table (ex. #t)

Then you can use `XML PATH` and `Stuff` to achieve your goal (later you can use that for whatever your purpose as inserting to a table or display in a report etc)

```
SELECT CaseKey, OwnerName, Address, (STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + Note
        FROM #t tx
        where tx.CaseKey = t.CaseKey and tx.OwnerName = t.OwnerName and tx.Address = t.Address 
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 2, '')
    ) AS StringValue
From #t t
Group by CaseKey, OwnerName, Address
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=45bdfb5cacc7f388ab66fb744ed0bb50)